# How to optimize file creation with large content in php

Tags: php, sql-server, magento, optimization, query-optimization

I have written a script to copy Mssql table to mysql table.Table contains more than 200000 rows. When Iam trying to create a file with 200000 rows it, facing  the execution timeout. even i have used batch processing into loop.

Please help me with optimised way to create file faster with large content.

Please see the code and help me with optimised way to copy large table from mssql to mysql

```
                $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
                $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
                $totalcount = 200000;

                $offset  = 0;
                $limit  = 900;
                $counter = 0;
                $cmpval = 0;


                while ($offset<$totalcount) {                   
                    $content = "";
                    $table="SELECT  * FROM emp ORDER BY id DESC OFFSET ".$offset." ROWS FETCH NEXT ".$limit." ROWS ONLY";
                    $tableResult = mssql_query($table,$link) or die(mssql_get_last_message());

                    $sql_rows = array();
                    while(list($name ,$desig, $dep) = mssql_fetch_array($tableResult)){                 



                                $sql_rows[] = ",$name,$desig, $dep,";
                                $counter++;

                    }

                    $content = implode('\n', $sql_rows);    
                    $aaaa = 'echo "'.$content.'" >> '.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/tmp/myText.txt';      
                    $out = shell_exec($aaaa);

                    // $offset  = $limit;
                    $offset  = $offset+$limit;
                    $cmpval = $totalcount-$offset;              
                    if($cmpval<$limit){                 
                        $limit = $cmpval;
                    }else{
                        $limit = $limit;
                    }                               
                }                                



                $qry1="LOAD DATA INFILE '".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/tmp/myText.txt"."' INTO TABLE emp FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';";

                $writeConnection->query($qry1);

                echo $counter." Total Records Inserted.";
```

Comment: Why don't you think to use MySQL Workbench, migration tool that can port direct from MS SQL database?

I used to do from MySQL to MS SQL: http://osify.com/2010/02/migrate-from-mysql-to-ms-sql-2005-using-ms-access-2003-as-a-bridge/#.WMedaK2SDCs

Comment: @Osify,Thanks for your reply. its basically scheduler process which runs on every day. it's not just one time activity.